# Dynamic add of content to simpleForm results in misaligned columns

Tags: sapui5

I am adding dynamically elements to two columns of SimpleForm. To have 2 columns I use `sap.ui.core.Title` as per https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm#controlProperties.

What I see though is that `sap.ui.core.Title` takes space.

[image]

I am trying to understand if it's a bug of UI5 or I am doing smth wrong. Here is a snippet of the function.

```
 _addCustomFieldsToEditDialog() {
      const fields = caseModel.getProperty('/INPUT_FIELDS');
      const form = this.getCustomFieldEditForm();
      const formDelimiter = new sap.ui.core.Title('form-delimiter', {});
      const leftFormContainer = [formDelimiter];
      const rightFormContainer = [formDelimiter];

      fields.forEach((field, index) => {
        const { label, inputControl } = this._editableCustomFieldFormElementFactory(field, dataPath);
        if (leftFormContainer.length === rightFormContainer.length) {
          leftFormContainer.push(label);
          leftFormContainer.push(inputControl);
        } else {
          rightFormContainer.push(label);
          rightFormContainer.push(inputControl);
        }
      });
      const elementsToAdd = [...leftFormContainer, ...rightFormContainer];
      elementsToAdd.forEach(el => form.addContent(el));
}
```

xml

```
<form:SimpleForm
    id="custom-fields-form-container-cancer"
    editable="true"
    layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
    labelSpanL="4"
    labelSpanM="4"
    emptySpanL="0"
    emptySpanM="0"
    columnsL="2"
    columnsM="2"
    class="editableForm">
</form:SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score -1):

this seems to be the correct UI5 behaviour.

If you have 2 Titles, it is aligned.
[image: 2 Titles]

If you have 1 Title, it is not.
[image: 1 Title]

If you have 1 Title and a small screen, this would not look odd at all.
[image: 1 Title small]

BTW: Be careful with ES6 notations. These won't work on IE11

Comment: I have 2 titles added to both columns in the code above

Comment: I still have the strong feeling that youronly have one title by reusing `formDelimiter`.
Please try it with 2 objects, one for each container.